# Xamarin ContentResolver/CursorLoader access in non-Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, service, xamarin, android-contentresolver

is it possible to access a Contentresolver when there is no activity (for example when i am trying to access it from a service)?

I have tried stuff with "Android.App.Context" and "Android.App.Activity" but without success.

Here is the Contentprovider i am trying to acccess (with an activity):

```
class ReceiveCallState : BroadcastReceiver

   public void AccessCallLog() 
   { 
      Android.Net.Uri uri = CallLog.ContentUri;

      string[] projection = {
                       CallLog.Calls.CachedName,
                       CallLog.Calls.Duration

                      };

       var cr = new CursorLoader(activity, uri, projection, null, null, null);
       var cursor = (ICursor)cr.LoadInBackground();
    }
}
```

And i would like to do this same call but without the activity object (or to somehow retrive the activity when it is not explicitly there)

edited: code. Added class from which is being inherited
kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve a `Context` to provide the `CursorLoader` constructor using `Android.App.Application.Context`.

For example:

```
Android.Content.Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;

// ...

var cr = new CursorLoader(context, uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

Comment: "Android.Content.Context" is not available in a class which is inheriting from Service or Broadcastreceiver

Comment: Huh, ok. Can you edit your question to include the class that's wrapping that call?

Comment: did it. In this particular case i am inheriting from a Broadcastreceiver. It would also be fine if i could access the contentresolver from a service (the _receiver is being registered by a service). Is it possible to somehow assign the "cursor" object in the activity and use it across the application (not as a global variable) ?

Comment: How is `AccessCallLog` being invoked? The docs say you receive a context in the `OnReceive` method of a BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: there is a saying in german: "Sometimes you dont see the forest because of all the trees" :). I was so hardly searching for the  context in the application environment that i missed the parameters in OnReceive :). I still cannot read the callLogs (i assume that this is some other issue - i set the permission READ_CALL_LOG) but i have tried it with the contacts-Uri and it worked fine. Thanks again